# memory alignment in the alloc_netdev_mqs

Tags: linux-kernel

Recently I study the linux network driver, and I have some problem for the memory alignment in the structure.

here is the code fragment for  in net/core/dev.c alloc_netdev_mqs:

```
alloc_size = sizeof(struct net_device)
if(sizeof_priv) 
{
    alloc_size = ALIGN(alloc_size, NETDEV_ALIGN) ---------(1)
    alloc_size += sizeof_priv;
}
/*ensure 32-byte alignment of whole construct*/
alloc_size += NETDEV_ALIGN - 1;                  ----------(2)
```

In the (1) place, I think it is reasonable to do ALIGN, since we want to align the struct net_device to the multiplier of NETDEV_ALIGN.

But in (2) place, in order to make alignment, why not use:
    ALIGN(alloc_size, NETDEV_ALIGN) again??

for example if we have : net_device 3 byte, NETDEV_ALIGN 4 byte, and private date 2 byte:

in (1) place we have ALIGN(3, 4) => 4byte
then the (private data size) + (net device size) = 4+2 = 6 byte

in (2) why not use ALIGN(6, 4) => 8byte ??

I just cannot figure out why, and not find answer by googling.
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that NETDEV_ALIGN=32 is more than alignment provided by kmalloc (at most 16 bytes). Because of that alignment of the structure is forced using additional padding:

```
p = kzalloc(alloc_size,...);
....
dev = PTR_ALIGN(p, NETDEV_ALIGN);
dev->padded = (char *)dev - (char *)p;
```

Additional value `NETDEV_ALIGN - 1` is used for provide bytes for padding (which can never exceed this value).

Comment: @AnakinTung: `kmalloc` (and related functions) garantees alignment suitable for any **native type**, which fits into size requested. E.g., on x86_64 pointer has size 8 bytes and should be aligned on 8 bytes for correct work. This type is the most alignment-restricted on given arch, so even you allocate 1024 bytes, `kmalloc` can return, e.g., 0x**************20. As you can see, this value is not aligned on 1024 bytes, but only on 8 bytes.

Comment: what you mean is that the pointer returned by kmalloc is not on 32byte aligned, so that why we need to add NETDEV_ALIGN to ensure that the padded bits are enough, right?

Comment: @AnakinTung: Yes, I mean exactly that.

Comment: I got it! thanks a lot~~ I should trace more code in the memory allocation aspect~